# "There is no one" or "There is no place"

Tags: sentence-construction

People eat rice all over India.If I change this sentence,

1. There is no one  in India who does not eat rice.
2. There is no place in India where rice is not eaten.
3. There is no place all over India where rice is not eaten.
4. There is no place in India where people do not eat rice.

Which is more natural?

Comment: #1 is a completely different statement from the others (which could all be true even if only *some* people in India eat rice, so long as the rice-eaters are evenly spread across the land). And *all* those last three are "unlikely", because most native speakers would probably use *There is **nowhere** in India [where...]* Other than that, apart from the completely non-idiomatic *no place / nowhere **all over** India* in #3, there's no reason to say any of the alternatives are "better" or more "natural" than others. It's just a stylistic choice of phrasing / emphasis.

Comment: I remember, http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour, You can't ask questions that are primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Years ago in a tiny Provençal town that had just suffered an onslaught of British tourists in caravans, I saw a large hand-lettered sign erected at the entrance to the vieille ville: **No Parking All Over The Place.**

Answer (score 1):

I think there are many way to write it, there aren't any reason to define what is "natural" and what isn't. The first sentences is wrong (It is difference between each sentences).

> There is no place in India where rice is not eaten.
>
> There is no place all over India where rice is not eaten.
>
> There is no place in India where people do not eat rice.

These are right.

There're other way to write that, You can use **There isn't any place in india where people don't eat rice.** or **Everyone in India eats rice** too.

#### Opinion

I think the best ways are **Everyone in India eats rice** and **There isn't any place in India where people don't eat rice**.

Why? Because I noticed that in English short sentences are often used and a lot of English people prefer use **any** than **no**.